# Should there be a に instead of を after クラスメイト in「それをクラスメイトを見られて以降」?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-を

In the following sentence is it correct to put the second を here?

> それをクラスメイト**を**見られて以降

Maybe it should be に? And if it's correct, how can we translate this part?

Here's the paragraph where the line is taken from

> 中学の夏休みだったーー。 旅行から帰って来たゆきを迎えに、駅前のバスターミナルで大きな車が待っていたそうだ。
>   それをクラスメイト**を**見られて以降、彼女は人の目をひく場所で、車に乗ることを嫌がるようになった。

Comment: 私も、『それをクラスメイト「に」見られて以来』のtypoだと思います・・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you cannot put two を since it marks a direct object. If I am correct, you would use this if the classmate can see something 「それをクラスメイトに見られて以降」. If you use を after classmate, I'm pretty sure it means that the classmate is the one being observed and most likely would be written as 「そのクラスメイトを見られて以降」. But I believe that you would want to use 「それをクラスメイトに見られて以降」. Sorry if I'm incorrect, I haven't gotten too far in my Japanese studies yet.